# merge 2 different datatable using DataRelation

Tags: c#, datatable

I tried to merge 2 datatables like [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f122d7f4-3b7d-4d93-bd0f-8bb57cd990a4/how-to-join-two-datatables-using-c-no-database-access?forum=adodotnetdataset). But my tables have different schema and different amount of rows. So I get an error here:

```
    DataRelation drel = new DataRelation("EquiJoin",cr1, cr2, true);
    dataSet.Relations.Add(drel);//error
```

As far as I understand, because first table has much more rows than second table.

```
   Error: Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack.
```

Tables look like:

```
    snowFlake:                              snow:
f_text  |   f_link_id   |    f_tabkey |   | f_text  |   f_link_id   |   f_tabkey  |
--------+---------------+-------------|   |---------+---------------+-------------|
row1    |    100001     |      1      |   |  -      |  100000       |     1       |
row2    |    100001     |      2      |   |  +      |  100001       |     1       |
row3    |    100001     |      3      |   |  -      |  100001       |     2       |
row4    |    100002     |      1      |   |  +      |  100001       |     3       |
row5    |    100003     |      1      |   |  +      |  100002       |     1       |
                                          |  +      |  100003       |     1       |
                                          |  -      |  100003       |     1       |
                                          |  +      |  100004       |     1       |
                                          |  -      |  100005       |     1       |
```

Primary keys that I use:

```
            snowFlake.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn [] { snowFlake.Columns[IndexesField.F_LINK_ID], snowFlake.Columns[IndexesField.F_TABKEY] };
            snow.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn [] { snow.Columns[IndexesField.F_LINK_ID], snow.Columns[IndexesField.F_TABKEY] };
            DataColumn[] cr1 = { snowFlake.Columns[IndexesField.F_LINK_ID], snowFlake.Columns[IndexesField.F_TABKEY] };
            DataColumn[] cr2 = { snow.Columns[IndexesField.F_LINK_ID], snow.Columns[IndexesField.F_TABKEY] };
```

How can I solve it?

Regards, Alexander.

Comment: What is the `error` exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter if they do not have same number of rows, because they are joined over a relation thus mimicking TSQL's Inner Join behavior. Without telling us the specific error, one can only assume that you haven't properly defined keys for joining (for example, the columns you specified in the relation don't exist).